# Does DistanceTransform not work in OpenCVSharp?

Tags: c#, opencv

My code is quite simple -- I am thresholding an image then attempting to apply `DistanceTransform` to it:

```
var source = new Mat(path, ImreadModes.AnyDepth | ImreadModes.AnyColor);
var bgr = new Mat[3];
var thresh = new Mat();
var dist = new Mat();
Cv2.Split(source, out bgr);
Cv2.AdaptiveThreshold(bgr[2], thresh, 255, AdaptiveThresholdTypes.MeanC, ThresholdTypes.Binary, 13, 2);
Cv2.ImShow("thresh", thresh);
Cv2.DistanceTransform(thresh, dist, DistanceTypes.L2, DistanceMaskSize.Mask5);
Cv2.ImShow("dist", dist);
```

But it's as if the filter is not applied at all:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out this was a failure to `Normalize` the image from 32 bits back down to 8 bits (as described by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8916645/84873)).

Upon adding the following line, the images are as expected:

```
Cv2.Normalize(dist, dist, 0, 1, NormTypes.MinMax);
```

[image]